# Concatenating Full Names in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

Suppose I have a table with the following information

```
Title   FirstName    MiddleName    LastName    Suffix
======|============|=============|============|======
Mr.    John         Fitzgerald    Kennedy      NULL
NULL   John         NULL          Doe          III
```

I want to create a query to output the full name of the above information. For example, I want the output to look like

```
Mr. John Fitzgerald Kennedy
John Doe, III
```

I was thinking of using the `concat()` function, but I am unsure how to go about this to ensure I don't have extra spaces or hanging commas in the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  SQL Server 2017+ supports `concat_ws()`.  However, you still need a comma for the suffix.  Forturnately, `concat()` ignores `NULL`s:

```
select concat(concat_ws(' ', title, firstname, middlename, lastname),
              ', ' + suffix
             )
```

Earlier versions require a bit more work to avoid multiple spaces when there are `NULL` values:

```
select ltrim(concat(' ' + title,
                    ' ' + firstname,
                    ' ' + middlename,
                    ' ' + lastname,
                    ', ' + suffix
                   )
            )
```

This uses the fact that `+` returns `NULL` when an argument is `NULL`.  But, `concat()` ignores it.

Note:  Neither probably does what you want if all the names are `NULL` but the suffix is present.  However, I doubt that is an issue in your data.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2544e44291c78f2af7e9d875d749962c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @325 . . . I don't understand your comment.  Both of these do *exactly* what you want (I added a db<>fiddle).  There is no extra comma if the suffix is real.  Read the "note" carefully.